# Is there a way to modify my SharePoint web URL to display a custom name instead of the servername/sites/intranet

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, deployment, url, alternate-access-mapping

I have created a new SharePoint 2013 web application, under the default port so the current web application URL is :-

```
http://servername/sites/Intranet/
```

But our client is asking if there is a way to modify the URL to be:-

```
http:compnayname.intranet
```

Can anyone advice who to do such a change?

Regards

**EDIT**

So I did the following:

1. I moved my site collection to be under the following path “servername:80/”.
2. Then on SharePoint administration I went to Configure alternate access mappings”“> “Edit Public Zone URLs “.
3. Under the Intranet I define `http://compnayname.intra`
4. And i leFT the Default as is `http://servername:portnumner`

So is this what is required from SharePoint side? As for the next step , I will inform our system administration to do the DNS part ?

Answer (score 2):

That is actually the recommended way of referencing a SharePoint site as it allows for such crazy things as load balancing and even, dare I say, replacing the physical server that runs SharePoint without breaking all of your bookmarks :)

Seriously, though.  Simply go into Central Administration, System Settings, Configure Alternate Access Mappings, select your web app on the top right and select `Edit Public URLs`.  Once there, simply add your `http://company.intranet` URL to one of the zones (Default or Intranet usually).  That is all it takes for SharePoint to listen for the new URL but sometimes you do need to add the new URL to the web app in IIS.  This does not happen often but I have seen it enough to warn about it.

Beyond that, you need to have your local DNS folks add the `http://company.intranet` alias and point it to your SharePoint server.

Comment: thanks for the replt. but currently i have these two site collections:- 1) http://servername:1234/sites/Intranet/ & 2)http://servername:1234/companyDiscussion/generalDiscussion/

Where both /sites/ & /companyDiscussion/ are managed paths. So is there a way modify the first URL to be :-
http://companyname.intra instead of http://servername:1234/sites/Intranet/ 
&
to modify the second URL to be http://companyname.intra/discussion instead of http://servername:1234/companyDiscussion/generalDiscussion/. ?

Comment: The 1234 is the port number as so there is no way to get rid of that without moving the site to another web application on port 80 with a different URL.  It is possible that Host-named site collections may be what you are looking for but I have little experience with those and cannot advise further there, however here is the MSDN info on them: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc424952.aspx

Comment: so if i move to be at port 80, then how i can chnage my URLs accordingly?

Comment: If you are ok with having /sites/ and /companyDiscussion/ under the same web app, you would do that precisely as I outline in the answer above. You first need to let sharepoint know what url to listen for, then make the DNS change to let the rest of your organization find the site on the new URL.  You may have to change the bindings in IIS for the SharePoint Website, as I mentioned.  You only need to worry about the `server:port` portion of the URL as everything after that will stay the same.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, since i have already created my web application and my site collection under servername:1234/sites/Intranet & servername:1234/companyDiscussion/generalDiscussion . so the best thing i can get in my case is to define AAM for my "servername:1234/sites" to be "http://company.intranet" inside SharePoint central admin . so the final URL will be something such as :- http://company.intranet/sites/Intranet ? and if i want to chnage anything after the servername:1234 , i will have to create a new managed path and restore the site collection under this new path ..? is the right ?

Comment: Changing `server:port` is completely different process from changing the relative path to the site collection within the site.  To do that, you need to backup up your current Site collections via the command line, create a new content database for your web application and remove (NOT delete!) the current contentDB from the web application then restore each site collection back into the new content DB database into the relative paths you wish.  Doing that would let you move your /sites/intranet/ down to the root of company.intranet/ instead of in the managed path.

Comment: can you check my edit please...

Comment: You now need to look at the web site bindings in IIS and make sure that the `company.intra` host is defined in the bindings for the SharePoint site (assuming SharePoint isn't just listening to all traffic on port 80 already, if so, you should be able to just leave that as is) then have your DNS folks add the entry